# React.js onShow event handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

I have a tabbed menu on my page, which is basically a bunch of divs that get shown/hidden depending on the tab that's clicked. I want to be able to refetch the data in a React Component in one of the divs once it appears.

`componentDidMount` fires at the very beginning, so it's not an option. It would be nice to just have an HTML event `onShow` similar to `onClick` but nothing like that seems to exist.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I have a Tabs component but in my case, all tabs content are mounted but not displayed. When I click on a tab, I just change the visibility with css

But to refetch data, you should make a component for the containers that fetch the data in his `componentDidMount` so, in the top level if you switch which one renders, the `componentDidMount` will trigger.

Put some code if you want some help with your case

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html), `componentDidUpdate` is probably what you're looking for.  It's called after `props` and/or `state` has changed and the component has re-rendered (not called for the initial render).

That said, it's probably simpler to just handle the data fetching in the `onClick` handler itself or better yet, fetch the data once in the parent component and pass down the relevant slice of data to the tabs and then show / hide as appropriate.

Comment: We need to see his code first but i am not agree with your answer. Tabs component should manage only tabs state like active and inactives!! (no data fetching!)

My Tabs components, are just "containers" for other components, like lists, graphs or whatever... so Tabs only manage his state about which tab is active (mounting it) and unmounting inactive tabs. 

When a tab is mounted, will mount his inner component and tab will finish his job.

And when the inner component is mounted, yo should handle data fetching (if u use that same component in another place, it will keep working!!)

Answer (score 0):

Hey You have to separate out the tab as component and render those component based on tab changed let me give one example over here.

Suppose I have one Page called MainPage in that Page I have Tab Control which Contain the Three tab First,Second and Third.

first you have to create a three Component like

```
var First=React.createClass({ // First Tab Content goes here });
var Second=React.createClass({// Second Tab Content goes here});
var Second=React.createClass({// Third Tab Content goes here});
```

Now your MainPage Should look like

```
 var MainPage=React.createClass({
        onClick:function(e)
        {
          if($(e.target).attr('id')=="1")
          {
           React.render(<First />,document.getElementById('tab-content'));
          }
           else if($(e.target).attr('id')=="2")
          {
           React.render(<Second />,document.getElementById('tab-content'));
          }
           if($(e.target).attr('id')=="3")
          {
           React.render(<Third />,document.getElementById('tab-content'));
          }
        },
        render:function()
        {
        return(
          <div>
            <div>
              //Three Tabl goes here 
              <div id="1" onClick={this.HandleTab}>Tab 1</div>
              <div id="2" onClick={this.HandleTab}> Tab 2</div>
              <div id="3" onClick={this.HandleTab}>Tab 3</div>
            </div>
            //your Container Div 
            <div id="tab-content">
            </div>
          </div>

        )
        }
})
```